# ubuntu command to get all function in a C++ program

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

I am searching for a tool that would help me get all the functions available in a C++ program along with the directory(if recursive call) that they are available in.

E.g. If run in folder1 in which folder2 exists were foo.c has int foo()

I would like to get int foo() directory folder2/foo.c

Comment: this post is definitely *not* off-topic.  This is a very good, definitely programming-related question.  IMHO...

Answer (score 3):

You can also look at tools like:

- [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/)
- [OpenGrok](http://opengrok.github.io/OpenGrok/)
- [LXR](http://lxr.linux.no/+trees)

Answer (score 2):

This is a very crude approximation, but might already get you closer to what you're looking for, and it has the advantage of being very simple. From the top-level directory of your code base, run:

```
find -name "*.h" -exec grep -H '^[^/]*(' {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you have Eclipse with CDT installed (http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/), you might just create a new project, import all your code and do a C/C++ search.

Answer (score 1):

ctags maybe what you want. http://ctags.sourceforge.net/

It is a tool for editors like vim or emacs to create tags. Those editors can use tags to find the declarations and definitions of functions and classes.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that when you speak of your *"C++ program"* you have access to all the C++ source files, and to its building, e.g. its `Makefile` etc.

If you have access to the produced binary, you could use `nm -C` on it to get the functions inside it.

Then, you might consider using some GCC extension or plugin. You could extend GCC with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) (which is a domain specific language to extend the GCC compiler). The [melt-examples/ex02](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-examples/tree/master/ex02) example is doing something quite similar (it is just counting functions, and you could add a few lines to make it output the name and source location of the currently counted function).

But notice that since GCC is optimizing, the notion of function inside a program might be less evident than what you imagine: GCC is cloning and inlining functions, and that means the set of functions in the generated program is not the set of functions in the source code.

The advantage of working inside the GCC compiler is that you really get the functions that the compiler is seeing. For example, textual approaches (like `ctags` or `grep` based answers) don't play well with preprocessing tricks.